# How can I remove elements in action menu odoo 11

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

How can I remove elements in action menu odoo 11?

I tried in settings->security

but the menu is still there

[image: elements in menu]

Answer (score 0):

To remove delete action from tree view, you can write `delete="0"` as following :

```
<tree string="Vehicle" delete="0" decoration-warning="contract_renewal_due_soon and not contract_renewal_overdue" decoration-danger="contract_renewal_overdue">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can delete/add actions in technical settings - window actions in that you search your model and delete or add action to specific model.

Answer (score -1):

You can remove Actions from `Settings >> Actions`.Do the group by `Binding Model` to easily understand your action.